# reasons for php hang

Tags: php

My hosting provider has suspended my account with a notice that php gets hang often.

They have also send usage report.

```
User  |  Domain | % CPU  | % MEM |  MySQL Processes 

lufadea1  lufadeal.com  20.88  1.30  0.6


13337 lufadea1  20   0  132m  17m 7656 R  2.3  0.1   0:00.07 /usr/bin/php/home/lufadea1/public_html/index.php

13346 lufadea1  20   0  129m  13m 7128 R  1.7  0.1   0:00.05 /usr/bin/php/home/lufadea1/public_html/index.php

13344 lufadea1  20   0  127m  10m 6204 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.04 /usr/bin/php/home/lufadea1/public_html/index.php

13347 lufadea1  20   0  126m  10m 6204 R  0.7  0.1   0:00.02 /usr/bin/php /home/lufadea1/public_html/index.php
```

I wants to know what are the possible reason which can cause the php hang problem.
I am using codeigniter framework. Let me know if you need any other information.Thanks.

Comment: The source code of `index.php` would help a lot

Comment: enable error reporting and check error logs. Update your codeigniter system folder to the latest version

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, being a .net developer, but my first question here would be why does your provider care that your application is hanging?  Presumably you aren't seeing any negative performance yourself - and if you are that should indicate where to look.

Comment: @JamesGaunt maybe he's on shared resources, and its application hanging reduces cpu and ram for other websites? It's a common practice to block the "bad codes", afaik. As for where they set the bar, that might be questionable

Comment: @BartVangeneugden This is a CodeIgniter's fron controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be many things. The first thing I'd check for are things like infinite loops, reading remote files, urls, ...

To avoid getting into trouble with your hosting provider you can use PHP's [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function to set a maximum time your script is allowed to run (before throwing an error).